# How can I update Azure VM BIOS settings?

Tags: azure, virtualization, remote-server, hyper-v, azure-virtual-machine

I have created an AZURE VM with Windows Server 2012 and started RDS installation.

I got stuck while it is asking me to Enable Hardware-Assisted Virtualization on the server, as I could not access BIOS through RDP.

How can I update Azure VM BIOS settings?

Any answers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do any modification on the BIOS plus the virtualization is not allowed on Windows Azure Virtual Machine, you cannot work with Virtualization over Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter the BIOS of the virtual machines. I'm curious why you're being asked to enable hardware-assisted virtualization - I'm guessing it's related to RDS that you mentioned. What is RDS in this case?